# import async function from the module

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have a function that looks like this

```
let fileCache = {};
async function generateFromFile(fullPath) {
    if (!fileCache[fullPath]) {
        let jsonResource = await fs.readFile(fullPath);
        fileCache[fullPath] = JSON.parse(jsonResource);
    }
    return fileCache[fullPath];
}
```

When I use it in the same module like this

```
await generateFromFile('myfile.json');
```

it works fine.

I created a separate file, put the function there and exported it like this

```
let fileCache = {};
async function generateFromFile(fullPath) {
    if (!fileCache[fullPath]) {
        let jsonResource = await fs.readFile(fullPath);
        fileCache[fullPath] = JSON.parse(jsonResource);
    }
    return fileCache[fullPath];
}

module.exports = {
    generateFromFile: generateFromFile
}
```

I imported it like this

```
const utils = require('../util/utils.js');
```

and wanted to use like `await utils.generateFromFile('myfile.json');` but it fails with the error

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function. Received undefined
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Can you share import statement for `fs`? Looks like you have imported traditional fs functions which expect callback function instead of promise based APIs and since no callback is passed here - `fs.readFile`, it is throwing error.

Comment: i think what you did is wrong, fs.readFile is not async, it takes callback, syntax of fs.readFile is `fs.readFile( filename, encoding, callback_function )`

Comment: @Raeesaa you are correct. I used import `const fs = require('fs')` instead of `const fs = require('fs').promises`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you import your fs module. To use `readFile` with `await` your should
either write `fs.promise.readFile`
or import `fs` as
`import { promises as fs } from 'fs'`

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that your newly created file is in the **relative** directory `../util/utils.js`? Your export looks fine. Maybe try to print out the imported `utils` object to see what you actually imported.

EDIT: You are also passing **relative** filenames to your function which is now in a different diretory than before. When accessing `fs.readFile(fullPath)` it tries to read the file inside the directory "util/". You should call your function with a full filepath like `util.generateFromFile(path.join(__dirname, "myfile.json"))` using the [path node package](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html).

EDIT 2: Like Raeesaa state you are using fs.readFile wrong. It does not return a Promise but expects a callback. To is it with `await` you have to [promisify](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) it like so:

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const { promisify } = require("util");
const readFileAsync = promisify(fs.readFile);

let fileCache = {};
async function generateFromFile(fullPath) {
    if (!fileCache[fullPath]) {
        let jsonResource = await readFileAsync(fullPath);
        fileCache[fullPath] = JSON.parse(jsonResource);
    }
    return fileCache[fullPath];
}

module.exports = {
    generateFromFile: generateFromFile
}
```

EDIT 3: If you only import JSON files you can do it by using `require`. Internally, require has also a cache so imports are only executed once. You can import JSON files as objects like so: `const obj = require("myfile.json");`

Comment: We no longer need to use `promisify` as filesystem module supports promises now. We just need to import promise based APIs - https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api

Comment: but this is not yet marked as a stable API

Comment: It still stable from node version 12 onwards as far as I remember.

Comment: huh you're right I can't find that it is not stable in the docs. It might have stuck in my mind because we're working on node v10 at my workplace and it was marked as experimental there...